# Ruby Minitest: Access variables in setup-method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

How can I access variables that are defined inside the setup method in Minitest?

```
require 'test_helper'

class TimestampTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  setup do
    @ag = AG.create(..., foo = bar(:foobar))
    @ap = AP.create(..., foo = bar(:foobar))
    @c  = C.create(..., foo = bar(:foobar))
  end

  [@ag, @ap, @c].each do |obj|
    test "test if #{obj.class} has a timestamp" do
      assert_instance_of(ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone, obj.created_at)
    end
  end
end
```

If I run this `@ag`, `@ap` and `@c` are all `nil`. bar(:foobar) on line 5-7 is needed to access fixture-data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating instance variables, and then later expecting them to exist in the class context. There's also an order of operations problem that you're missing: The `setup` method is run only after the class is fully defined, yet you're immediately exercising those variables to define the class.

If you need those to execute immediately, remove the `setup do ... end` block. It's also better to follow Ruby conventions and define it like this:

```
class TimestampTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  CLASSES = [
    AG,
    AP,
    C
  ]

  setup do
    @time_zones = CLASSES.map do |_class|
      [
        class.name.downcase.to_sym,
        _class.create(...)
      ]
    end.to_h
  end

  test "test if things have a timestamp" do
    @time_zones.each do |type, value|
      assert_instance_of(ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone, value.created_at)
    end
  end
end
```

As a note, your pseudo-code with a method call of the form `(..., foo=...)` creates an extraneous variable `foo` for no reason. That should be omitted unless you meant `foo: ...` where that's a named keyword argument.